# WDK offline installer - Downloads files from the internet

Tags: wdk

I downloaded the WDK Webinstaller from the Microsoft portal. Using the **/layout  /features +**  command line options, i created an offline installer for WDK.

Using this offline installer, i performed a silent installation using the following command:

**WDK8.1Install.exe /quiet /NoRestart /log "C:\Users\kiranh\AppData\Local\ChocoCache\Logs\WDK8.1\8.100.26846\Install.log"**

With an offline installer, i would have expected nothing to be downloaded from the internet. However, i see that there are a lot of bits which are being downloaded from the internet.

Could someone tell me the reason as to why bits are being downloaded from the internet?

I have also observed that at times, nothing is downloaded from the internet. However, that seems to be only when the WDK has been installed atleast once on the system.

Here is an excerpt from the log:

```
*Resolving download root for: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=392876
[0CEC:0F54][2018-02-16T01:46:32]: HTTP status code: 302
[0CEC:0F54][2018-02-16T01:46:32]: Redirected URL: http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/8/C/08C7497F-8551-4054-97DE-60C0E510D97A/wdk/
[0CEC:0F54][2018-02-16T01:46:32]: Resolved redirected download root: http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/8/C/08C7497F-8551-4054-97DE-60C0E510D97A/wdk/
[0CEC:0F54][2018-02-16T01:46:32]: package_WindowsDebuggingVSIntegrationDev12x86_en_us to http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/8/C/08C7497F-8551-4054-97DE-60C0E510D97A/wdk/Installers/Windows Debugging VS Integration Dev12-x86_en-us.msi
[0CEC:0F54][2018-02-16T01:46:32]: Acquiring package: package_WindowsDebuggingVSIntegrationDev12x86_en_us, payload: package_WindowsDebuggingVSIntegrationDev12x86_en_us, download from: http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/8/C/08C7497F-8551-4054-97DE-60C0E510D97A/wdk/Installers/Windows Debugging VS Integration Dev12-x86_en-us.msi
[0DE0:02EC][2018-02-16T01:46:32]: Verified acquired payload: package_WindowsDebuggingVSIntegrationDev12x86_en_us at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\package_WindowsDebuggingVSIntegrationDev12x86_en_us, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{96C0E1F9-960D-B927-8A62-90B39E59D0CA}v8.100.26846\Installers\Windows Debugging VS Integration Dev12-x86_en-us.msi.
[0CEC:0F54][2018-02-16T01:46:32]: Prompt for source of package: package_WindowsDebuggingVSIntegrationDev12x86_en_us, payload: pay867C14C04262152841173685F0E711B0, path: C:\Users\kiranh\AppData\Local\ChocoCache\WDK8.1\8.100.26846\Installers\1c33d17316f25da4cbe42ca09b018509.cab
[0CEC:0F54][2018-02-16T01:46:32]: pay867C14C04262152841173685F0E711B0
[0CEC:0F54][2018-02-16T01:46:32]: pay867C14C04262152841173685F0E711B0 to http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/8/C/08C7497F-8551-4054-97DE-60C0E510D97A/wdk/Installers/1c33d17316f25da4cbe42ca09b018509.cab
[0CEC:0F54][2018-02-16T01:46:32]: Acquiring package: package_WindowsDebuggingVSIntegrationDev12x86_en_us, payload: pay867C14C04262152841173685F0E711B0, download from: http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/8/C/08C7497F-8551-4054-97DE-60C0E510D97A/wdk/Installers/1c33d17316f25da4cbe42ca09b018509.cab
[0DE0:02EC][2018-02-16T01:46:33]: Verified acquired payload: pay867C14C04262152841173685F0E711B0 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\pay867C14C04262152841173685F0E711B0, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{96C0E1F9-960D-B927-8A62-90B39E59D0CA}v8.100.26846\Installers\1c33d17316f25da4cbe42ca09b018509.cab.
[0CEC:0F54][2018-02-16T01:46:33]: Prompt for source of package: package_WindowsDebuggingVSIntegrationDev12x86_en_us, payload: payF179DC1C4866F63F7BB9057BF1AD363D, path: C:\Users\kiranh\AppData\Local\ChocoCache\WDK8.1\8.100.26846\Installers\b6923fe117b94abbb1703c09cf619759.cab
[0CEC:0F54][2018-02-16T01:46:33]: payF179DC1C4866F63F7BB9057BF1AD363D
[0CEC:0F54][2018-02-16T01:46:33]: payF179DC1C4866F63F7BB9057BF1AD363D to http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/8/C/08C7497F-8551-4054-97DE-60C0E510D97A/wdk/Installers/b6923fe117b94abbb1703c09cf619759.cab
[0CEC:0F54][2018-02-16T01:46:33]: Acquiring package: package_WindowsDebuggingVSIntegrationDev12x86_en_us, payload: payF179DC1C4866F63F7BB9057BF1AD363D, download from: http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/8/C/08C7497F-8551-4054-97DE-60C0E510D97A/wdk/Installers/b6923fe117b94abbb1703c09cf619759.cab
[0DE0:02EC][2018-02-16T01:46:33]: Verified acquired payload: payF179DC1C4866F63F7BB9057BF1AD363D at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\payF179DC1C4866F63F7BB9057BF1AD363D, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{96C0E1F9-960D-B927-8A62-90B39E59D0CA}v8.100.26846\Installers\b6923fe117b94abbb1703c09cf619759.cab.
[0CEC:0F54][2018-02-16T01:46:33]: Prompt for source of package: package_WindowsDebuggingWDKIntegrationx86_en_us, payload: package_WindowsDebuggingWDKIntegrationx86_en_us, path: C:\Users\kiranh\AppData\Local\ChocoCache\WDK8.1\8.100.26846\Installers\Windows Debugging WDK Integration-x86_en-us.msi
[0CEC:0F54][2018-02-16T01:46:33]: package_WindowsDebuggingWDKIntegrationx86_en_us
[0CEC:0F54][2018-02-16T01:46:33]: package_WindowsDebuggingWDKIntegrationx86_en_us to http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/8/C/08C7497F-8551-4054-97DE-60C0E510D97A/wdk/Installers/Windows Debugging WDK Integration-x86_en-us.msi
[0CEC:0F54][2018-02-16T01:46:33]: Acquiring package: package_WindowsDebuggingWDKIntegrationx86_en_us, payload: package_WindowsDebuggingWDKIntegrationx86_en_us, download from: http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/8/C/08C7497F-8551-4054-97DE-60C0E510D97A/wdk/Installers/Windows Debugging WDK Integration-x86_en-us.msi*
```

Answer (score 0):

All I am going to say is that I've used the offline installer myself on environments in which no active internet connection was available on, and the installer worked perfectly fine. Which must mean the offline installer can't be dependent on having an internet connection like the normal one.

Your best bet is asking Microsoft directly yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it again

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have finally found out the reason for WDK/SDK installers defaulting to the web, after a year of trying out various approaches. In our case, the WDK/SDK installers are installed by downloading an iso file , mounting this iso file, and then invoking the installer from this mounted iso file. The key reason for this behavior is that we are using the Chocolatey cmdlet: **Install-ChocolateyPackage**
to install the WDK/SDK packages.  In our case, the Chococache location is set to %appdata%\local\ChocoCache, at the time of installation of the WDK/SDK Choco packages.
When the cmdlet Install-ChocolateyPackage is used, the WDK/SDK installers set the source of the offline installer to the ChocoCache location under %appdata%\local\ChocoCache<ChocoPackage id>, instead of setting the location to the location of the mounted iso file. With the installation source being set to %appdata%\local\ChocoCache<ChocoPackage id>, the offline installer is never found, and hence, the WDK installer executable attempts to download installers from the Web. Most of the time, the download from the web is successful. However, there are times due to network glitches, the download fails and hence the installation of WDK/SDK fails.

Additionally, the WDK/SDK installers log the offline installer location using a Wix bundle property: **WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder**.
This was being incorrectly set to %appdata%\local\ChocoCache<ChocoPackage id>. This is what helped me in finally figuring out the root cause. **Install-ChocolateyPackage** should only be used for installers that are downloaded from the Web and installed by the cmdlet. When you use Install-ChocolateyPackage to install offline installers, the cmdlet copies the installation executable to %appdata%\local\ChocoCache<ChocoPackage id> and executes the installer from here.

As you can clearly see, this means that the WDK/SDK installer executable will never find the offline installation packages. Hence, they default to the web.

Fix is to use an alternative cmdlet:**Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage**